# How to update navbar in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing react project,
my navbar has an login button

In Navigation.js, 
I check if the user is logined with

```
const authenticated = user != null;
```

and decide to show login or logout

```
{authenticated ? (
        <LogoutButton logout={logout} />
      ) : (
          <Link to="/login">
            <button>Login</button>
          </Link>

        )}
```

But the problem is that after login, the navigation bar is not updated to logout.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include the Navigation component and the component that holds the state of the user?

Comment: are you using class Component or function Component ?

Comment: I am using fuction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Navigation class

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        authenticated : null
    };
};

componentDidMount() {
    // Call this function here or anywhere like user login event
    this.setState({authenticated : user != null});
}
```